# Select данных при условии

Tags: postgresql

как можно выбрать все данные из таблицы, у которых в одном поле повторяются данные ?

т.е. как выполнить вот такое

`select поле1, поле2, поле3 from table where поле1 {.....} having count(1) > 9;` без группировки оно не работает

аргумент конструкции WHERE должен иметь тип boolean, а не character varying

`select поле1, поле2, поле3 from table where поле1 {......} group by поле1, поле2, поле3 having count(1) > 9` - работает - но это жесть, так как при группировке ничего нет - все строки уникальны, и группировка дает null, но SQL запрос без ошибок)

Answer (score 1):

Ну однозначно будет работать

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, COUNT(field1) OVER (PARTITION BY field1) cnt
              FROM table )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 9
```

Comment: да, совсем забыл про over with cte спасибо